How to use css class name autocomplete in pug files inside vsCode?
I have 2 simple files (index.pug and style.css) and i need css class name autocomplete in pug file. i changed emmet settings too but it does not work. (I need something like tailwindcss extension)
I tested this settings:
Show Expanded Abbreviation: (never, always)
Use Inline Completions : (on, off)
Show Suggestions As Snippets: (of, off)

